# MySQL - What is the difference between tinytext and varchar?

Tags: mysql, varchar, tinytext

I've been coding php/mysql for years under the assumption that varchar was meant for when you know the length of the input string - e.g. if report numbers are always 20 characters alphanumeric. Alternatively, I always thought Tinytext should be used when you want to limit a string to between 0 and 255 bytes, but have it be variable size (like a username field).

Reading the spec today on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html, it seems like varchar and tinytext are exactly the same - a variable-length string whose limit is between 0 and 255 bytes. What's the difference between the two? What are the intended use cases for each?

Comment: Your description of what you thought `varchar` was is actually more of what `char` is. `Char` allocates as much space as you define in your table, regardless of the actual length of your value. `Varchar` only allocates as much space as your value uses, but if you use, for instance, `VARCHAR(20)`, then it's not a memory allocation rule, but  just your own limitation to make sure you don't get a value you aren't expecting. So if your value is 'abcd', it still only uses 4 bytes of memory, but if your value is longer than 20 chars, the DB will throw an error.

Comment: If you use `CHAR(20)` and your value is 'abcd', the DB will still allocate 20 bytes of memory, even though you're not using it. So `CHAR` is best when all values are always the same length.